# jQuery.param with lists

Tags: jquery, asp-classic

Does anybody here knows how do I use jQuery.param to create an **object with a list of phone numbers** and how do I supose to recover that in classical ASP?

I use $.ajax to send to an ASP page the parametres. Usually what I do is something like that:

```
var p = {
    cod: cod.val(),
    name: name.val()
};
var param = jQuery.param(p);
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "SomeASP.asp",
    data: param 
});
```

I using **var param = jQuery.param(p);** because my string can contain any character, like & or ? or spaces. And than I recover the information at "SomeASP.ASP" by doing this:

```
Dim cod, name
cod = Request("cod")
name= Request("name")
```

**The main problem is**: Now I have to send a list o phone numbers to "SomeASP.asp".
I read the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/) and notice that I can send a more complex object than I demonstrate above, but I have no idea of how to send and to recover these items.

I appreciate any help! Sorry for my poor english.

[]'s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need `jQuery.param(p);`.

Simply do:

```
var p = {
    cod: cod.val(),
    name: name.val()
};

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "SomeASP.asp",
    data: p 
});
```

In this case jQuery will serialize `p` correctly and on server side you will be able to do

```
Dim cod, name
cod = Request("cod")
name= Request("name")
```

**UPD:**

Not sure how ASP will handle such request. In asp.net it would be:

```
string[] = Request["phones[]"].Split(",");
```

Possibly something like that you will need to do in classic asp.

But if no, you may join phone numbers on client:
var p = {
        cod: cod.val(),
        name: name.val()
    };
    p.phones = ['phone1', 'phone2'].join(",")//you should receive string like "phone1,phone2"
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "SomeASP.asp",
        data: p 
    });

and than on server side:

```
Dim cod, name, phones
cod = Request("cod")
name= Request("name")
phones = Request("phones")
phonesArray = phones.Split(",") //not sure how exactly this line will be in classic asp, but idea should be clear
```

Comment: I need because I can send anything at the string.. like & or ?

Comment: And have you tried to send a simple array? Like `p.phones = ['phone1', 'phone2']` and than send it. You do not need param there. Jquery will do the same on object when sending an ajax request. After you do an ajax call what are you getting from `Request("phones")`?

Comment: I think I don't understand. Do you mean something like var p = {
    cod: cod.val(),
    name: name.val(),
    phone: ['phone1', 'phone2'] };

Comment: I'll try, Thank you! Any suggestion of recovering it on ASP?

Comment: Meanwhile - see what exactly are you getting in `Request('phones')`. Possibly it will even parse it correctly and you will get an array.